# Theorem box extending over footnote causing page split

Tags: footnotes, amsthm, thmtools, thmbox

I have a document where I'm using `amsthm` and `thmtools` (particularly `thmbox`) for formatting some definitions. The document also contains some footnotes, which are reasonably-sized (i.e. not more than ~1/4th of the page).

### The problem

If a definition stretches over a page, it overflows onto the next, which is not a problem. However, if the definition stretches "over" a footnote (i.e. it goes over a pagebreak where the page ends in with a footnote), there's a weird rendering issue where the start of the definition gets pushed onto its own, otherwise empty, page.

#### Example

```latex
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[thmbox=M, style=definition, name=Definition]{defn}

\begin{document}

Long paragraph pushing the definition over the page.
\footnotemark


\footnotetext{This long footnote means that the beginning of the definition cannot stay on page 1. (BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH )}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}


\begin{defn}
    Long definition spanning across two pages
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

forces the start of Definition 1 onto a new page. This doesn't happen if `thmbox` is not set.

[image: An example of a bad definition rendering due to a footnote.]

#### What's going on?

It looks almost like `amsthm` is laying out the definition correctly, then the footnote comes in and, not having enough space to be rendered, shuffles over the end bit of the page. The only issue is that the definition on the next page (and the rest of the document) are not shuffled along to compensate. Instead, the problematic part of the definition is just placed on a new page, to give it the necessary space.

Comment: Hi, I'm the current maintainer of `thmtools`. The problem is reproducible with `thmbox` environment from `thmbox` package. It seems that `thmbox` does not take the height of footnote into account when preparing for page break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is reproducible with `thmbox` package alone, see the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{thmbox}

\begin{document}
Long paragraph pushing the definition over the page.\footnote{\lipsum[23]}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{thmbox}[M]{\bfseries Definition}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{thmbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compared to the page-breaking algorithm used by `tcolorbox` package (more specifically, its source file [`tcbbreakable.code.tex`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/master/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbbreakable.code.tex), the definition of macro `\tcb@comp@h@page`), I find replacing `\vsize` with `\pagegoal` in definition of `\thmbox@start` solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M, style=definition, name=Definition]{defn}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
% replace all \vsize by \pagegoal in definition of \thmbox@start
\xpatchcmd*\thmbox@start
  {\vsize}
  {\pagegoal}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Long paragraph pushing the definition over the page.\footnote{\lipsum[23]}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{defn}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

[image]